# Unable to connect to windows shares without restart

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares, login

Question:I've an annoying problem with windows 7:

I cannot connect to windows shares in the local network when I join the network before I booted up.

The thing is, it works fine after I restart, but I cannot log-in without restarting.
It has nothing to do with login, because I cannot access the shares when I logout and login again, either - that is - if I don't restart. It only works when I restart.

This is soooo annoying.

Anybody knows what the problem is ?
Or does this have something to do with disconnecting the computer without logging-out the previous day ?
I think it has nothing to do with the network at all.
 I think the connection of the previous day is still somewhere in RAM locally.
So if I don't restart, then it's trying to use a connection that has been invalidated...

Comment: Can you `ping` the machines where the other shares are location and have you checked `ipconfig`? Just to rule out the possibility that it is an issue with your network connectivity. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "join the network before I booted up" - how can you join a network *before* starting the machine up?

Comment: Try this command in a 'DOS box' window: `net use`. Does it show any shares which might already be connected`? Then type `net use * \\servername\sharename`. Does it give you an error message? If yes, which one?

Comment: Funny, first it doesn't work, then I type net use \\servername\sharename which says that everything is ok. And then it works afterwards... - every time.

Comment: net use shows several connections, all of them "connected" , but I can not navigate inside them. If I use net use \\server\share it says "System error 64" . WTF!! I have this OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opeing a console and typing

```
net use \\servername\sharename
```

solves the problem...